# read data from a url and stream it back to client with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I'm still new to Ruby and Rails so please excuse my question if the answer is obvious.  I have an application running with a controller called `bucket` which when passed an `id` connects to a non-routable subnet (10.0.0.xx) and returns data assuming some conditions are met.  I'm currently using the `send_data` method in the `bucket` controller but since this expects a local file I'm reading the contents of the url into a string and then returning that.

This is good enough for very small files but for large binaries it's too slow.  What I really want to be able to do is stream the data back using /bucket as a proxy.

Here is the code from the controller I'm currently using:

```
fileName = "somename.dat"        
content = open(link) {|f| f.read() }
send_data content, :disposition=>'attachment', :filename=>fileName
```

I was hoping someone may have some advice on how to improve this.  Ideally, I could read the data in chunks and return it as I received it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [rack-proxy](https://github.com/ncr/rack-proxy), which will read from the private server and pass on the data for you.

Install by adding `gem 'rack-proxy'` to your [`Bundle`](http://gembundler.com/rails3.html)

To configure, subclass.

Example:

```
class FooBar < Rack::Proxy

  def rewrite_env(env)
    env["HTTP_HOST"] = "example.com"

    env
  end

  def rewrite_response(triplet)
    status, headers, body = triplet

    headers["X-Foo"] = "Bar"

    triplet
  end

end
```

For more examples, read [the tests](https://github.com/ncr/rack-proxy/tree/master/test).

As a rack app, rack-proxy can be [mounted in your rails 3 app](http://inductor.induktiv.at/blog/2010/05/23/mount-rack-apps-in-rails-3/) as simply as:

```
mount FooBar, :at => "/foo_bar"
```

If you want to find out more about the role rack plays in the Rails ecosystem, here are [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html).

If you don't like this proxy, or you want some more ideas, [check out a different implementation](https://github.com/aniero/rack-streaming-proxy).

Comment: in order to test this i created a new rails app created the class listed about and added the route listed here, but when i start 'rails server' i get /Users/<blah>/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@rails304/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:163:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)

Comment: If you think you've discovered an issue with the gem, feel free to [create a new issue](https://github.com/ncr/rack-proxy/issues/new)

Comment: I'm sorry is this working for you? or did you just copy and paste from the doc for rack-proxy?

Comment: subclass example copied & pasted. You'll need to write your own subclass, in case that wasn't clear. There are examples in [the test folder](https://github.com/ncr/rack-proxy/tree/master/test).

Comment: Right, I didn't expect the FooBar subclass to solve the problem.  But , it appears at the very least that Rack::Proxy isn't itself a rack app so it can't at the very least be mounted as you state.  I think that's the problem.

Comment: Took author's word for it: "A request/response rewriting HTTP proxy. A Rack app." If that's true, then try the [rack middleware](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) that was [previously linked](https://github.com/aniero/rack-streaming-proxy) instead.

Comment: not quite i had to move on to other stuff, I couldn't quite get it working.